# BlackBerry webworks app installation error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I have developed an application for BlackBerry with WebWorks in OSX; I installed  the SDK and Ripple, I get and installed the .csi files, and the software version of my BlackBerry is 5.0 Bundle 1419. I packaged and signed the app, but when I try to install the app using the BlackBerry Desktop Software it throws me this error:

**BlackBerry Desktop Software failed to validate your BlackBerry device update.**
Aborting install due to validation failure. Some packages contained unsatisfied dependencies.

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="1.0.0.7"
        rim:header="RIM-Widget: rim/widget">

  <author href="http://www.xyz.com/" rim:copyright="Name xyz">Name xyz</author>
  <name>Name xyz</name>

  <description>
    App xyz
  </description>

  <content src="index.html" />

  <access uri="http://xyz.com/" subdomains="true" />

  <rim:connection timeout="25000">
    <id>TCP_WIFI</id>
    <id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
  </rim:connection>

  <license>
    Copyright (c) 2011 XYZ
    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
    EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
    MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
    NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS
    BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
    ACTION OF CONTRACT, INSULT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
    CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
    SOFTWARE.
  </license>

</widget>
```

Did I miss something? what could be the problem? thanks in advance

Comment: I think the Blackberry webworks supported greater than version 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with your application.  For some reason, the desktop software doesn't like the OS installed on your BlackBerry.

Suggest upgrading to the latest version of the desktop software and trying again.

Otherwise, you can side load your app using javaloader OR deploy the files found in the OTAInstall folder to a webserver and install your app through the browser (by browsing to the *.jad file).  More info about deployment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794